# How to find marginal density from joint density?

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

Let $$\begin{gather*}
X  \sim \text{Uniform}(-1, 1),\\
\varepsilon \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1),\\
Y=X+\varepsilon X,
\end{gather*}$$
where $\varepsilon$ and $X$ are independent. I need to find $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. Firstly, to find $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$ we can fix $X = x_0$, where $x_0$ is const(we consider two cases, $x_0 > 0$ and $x_0 < 0$). Then , in the first case $Y = x_0 + \varepsilon x_0$ is distributed as $\text{Uniform}(x_0, 2x_0)$. Similary done for the second case we get

\begin{equation*}
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = 
 \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{X}\mathbb{I}_{[X,2X]}(Y) &\text{X > 0}\\
   -\frac{1}{X}\mathbb{I}_{[2X,X]}(Y) &\text{X < 0}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Where $\mathbb{I}_{[2X,X]}$ is Indicator function.
Then we can find a joint density $$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_X f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{2X}\mathbb{I}_{[X,2X]}(Y)\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(X) &\text{X > 0}\\
   -\frac{1}{2X}\mathbb{I}_{[2X,X]}(Y)\mathbb{I}_{[-1,0]}(X) &\text{X < 0}
 \end{cases}
$$

But I'm stuck with marginal density $f_Y(y)$. By definition, $f_Y(y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X, Y}(x, y)dx$ but this integral doesn't converge. So, my question is, have I made a mistake? (I think I might be mistaken with computing $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$, but I don't know where)

Answer (score 2):

In solving such probability problems, **whenever you can, draw a picture: it brings insight and prevents many mistakes.**

[image: Figure]

*This figure depicts 5,000 randomly-drawn $(x,y)$ pairs from this distribution.  To it I have added the lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$ and the boundary of the rectangle $[-1,1]\times[-2,2]$ that delineate the possible values of $(x,y).$  The dotted line is explained below.*

#### The conditional distributions

From the construction--as evidenced in the figure--it is clear that $Y,$ conditional on $X=x,$ has a uniform distribution with values between $x+0x$ and $x+1x=2x.$ Therefore its density function is supported on the interval $[x,2x]$ (or $[2x,x]$ when $x\lt 0$) and because that interval has length $|x|,$ the density on that interval equals $1/|x|.$  If you like, you may express that in terms of indicator functions as

$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = \mathbb{I}_{[x,2x]}(y)\, \frac{1}{|x|},$$

understanding that when $x\lt 0,$ "$[x,2x]$" means the interval from $2x$ to $x.$  Clearly this is equivalent to what you wrote--but please take note of the distinctions between *numbers* $x$ and $y$ and *random variables* $X$ and $Y.$

#### The marginal distribution

**The picture guides us:** it suffices to consider only $-2 \le y \le 2.$ It often is simpler to compute a cumulative distribution function $F_Y$ (and differentiate it if you really need the density $f_Y$), so we might start with that.  Here, its value at $y$ would be the total probability below the horizontal line at height $y.$

**The picture suggests another simplification:** the probability density is symmetrical under a 180 degree rotation around the origin.  This means the marginal destribution of $Y$ will be symmetrical about $0.$  It suffices, therefore, to perform the *simpler* integrals involved when $y \le 0;$ we can then set $F_Y(y) = 1 - F_Y(-y)$ for $y\ge 0.$

The figure gives an example where $y=-1/2,$ shown by the dotted line.
Because the distribution is given conditionally in terms of $X,$ *let's integrate over $x.$*  For each $x,$ the integral must extend from $0$ to $y.$  Once more the picture helps: the $x$ integration need only extend from $x=-1$ to $x=y/2 \le 0,$ while for each $x$ the integral extends from $2x to x.$

**The picture helps yet again in two ways:**

1. The integral when $-1\lt y \le 0$ should be performed in two pieces: one for $x=-1$ to $x=y$ (which is so easy you can just write down the answer) and a second for $x=y$ to $x=y/2.$
2. When $-2\le y \lt 1,$ there's just one piece from $x=-1$ to $x=y/2.$

The principle behind these integrals comes from the formula

$$F_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

It says you need to integrate the *cumulative* distribution of $Y,$ conditional on $x,$ multiplied by the marginal density of $x.$  The cumulative conditional distributions are obvious in the picture: for any $x \le 0,$ express $y$ as a proportion of the distance from $2x$ upward towards $x$ (and clamp this to the range $[0,1]$).  *Knowing this will help verify any algebraic approach you take to solving the problem using integrals and indicator functions.*  (In fact, it makes it possible to write down the integrals directly without any more work.)

**I'll leave you to work out the details,** but as an example will perform one of the more difficult calculations: the case $-2\le y \lt 1.$  At any relevant value of $x,$ the total probability is $(y - 2x)/|x|$ and this has to be integrated from $x=-1$ to $x=y/2$ against the density for $X,$ which is constantly $1/2.$  Writing $|x|=-x,$ this gives

$$\int_{-1}^{y/2} \frac{y-2x}{-x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2}$$

which is elementary to work out (and will involve the logarithm of $-y/2.$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: $x < y < 2x$ is equivalent to $\frac{y}{2} < x < y$. This translates to your indicator in your last integral.

Hint 2: Indicators in integrals are indeed integral boundaries.

Hint 3: $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2x}$ has a nice antiderivative, defined at every point except 0 (which does not hurt). Meaning "but this integral doesn't converge" is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what does Hint 1 mean? By hint 2 boudaries in integrals are $[0,1]$ and $[-1,0]$, isn't it true?

Comment: In hint 1 it means, you can rewrite $\mathbb{I}_{ \left[x,2x\right]}\left(y\right)$ as  $\mathbb{I}_{ \left[\frac{y}{2},y\right]}\left(x\right)$.

Then a new hint 1.5 would apply, which states, you can rewrite the product of two indicators as one indicator.